# Scala type error with Try[Int]

Tags: scala, foldleft

I have a problem with types that I don't understand. In the code below I have two methods `half1` and `half2` which are exactly the same except `half1`'s return type is specified explicitly. Yet when I use the two methods in a foldLeft `half` causes a compiler error. Here is the code. The line that sets `val c` has the problem.

```
package org.bodhi.reactive.`try`

import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

object Hello {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val list = List(1,2,3)

    Try(1024).flatMap(half1)
    Try(1024).flatMap(half2)

    half1(1024).flatMap(half1)
    half2(1024).flatMap(half2)

    val a = list.foldLeft(Try(1024))((accum, n) => accum.flatMap(half1))
    val b = list.foldLeft(half1(1024))((accum, n) => accum.flatMap(half1))
    val c = list.foldLeft(half2(1024))((accum, n) => accum.flatMap(half2)) // Compiler error

  }

  def half1(n: Int): Try[Int] =  
    if (n % 2 == 0) Success(n / 2)
    else Failure(new Exception(s"WRONG $n"))

  def half2(n: Int) =
    if (n % 2 == 0) Success(n / 2)
    else Failure(new Exception(s"WRONG $n"))
}
```

The error I get is:

```
[error] /home/chris/projects/reactive/example/src/main/scala/org/bodhi/reactive/try/Hello.scala:18: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.util.Try[Int]
[error]  required: Product with Serializable with scala.util.Try[Int]
[error]     val c = list.foldLeft(half2(1024))((accum, n) => accum.flatMap(half2))
```

My question is: why does `half1` comile in foldLeft, but `half2` does not?
I am using scala 2.11.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `Success` and `Failure` extend `Try[T] with Product with Serializable`, (`Product with Serializable` because they are case classes). So when you leave the return type off of `half2`, it's returned type is inferred as `Try[T] with Product with Serializable`.

Normally this doesn't matter, `flatMap(half2)` will still return `Try[T]`

```
scala> Try(1024).flatMap(half2)
res2: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(512)
```

But `foldLeft` is a different story. The problem is when you pass `half(2)` as the first argument. Let's look at the signature of `foldLeft`:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B
```

`B` is inferred from the argument `z`, which means

```
B = Try[T] with Product with Serializable
```

That means that `op` is expected to have the type:

```
(A, Try[T] with Product with Serializable) => Try[T] with Product with Serializable
```

But instead it's `(A, Try[T]) => Try[T]`, and thus you get a type mismatch. Using type inference can be nice, but most of the time explicitly typing your return types will save you a lot of headaches.